# multiple custom post type not being registered in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

```
function custom_post_type(){

    //post type for popular sight seeing

    $labels = array(
        'name' => _x( 'popular_site_seeing', 'Post Type General Name', 'travel' ),
        'singular_name'=> _x( 'popular_site_seeing', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'travel' ),

        );

    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'popular_site_seeing', 'travel' ),
        'description'         => __( 'popular_site_seeing', 'travel' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,

        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),



        'taxonomies'          => array( 'genres' ),

        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        );

    // Registering popular_site_seeing
    register_post_type( 'popular_site_seeing', $args);



    //post type for popular_treking_climbing

    $labels= array(
        'name' => _x( 'popular_treking_climbing', 'Post Type General Name', 'travel' ),
        'singular_name'=> _x( 'popular_treking_climbing', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'travel' ),

        );

    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'popular_treking_climbing', 'travel' ),
        'description'         => __( 'popular_treking_climbing', 'travel' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,

        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'author', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'revisions', 'custom-fields', ),


        'taxonomies'          => array( 'genres' ),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'has_archive'         => true,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'post',
        );







    //registering popular_treking_climbing
    register_post_type( 'popular_treking_climbing', $args);




}



add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_type' );
```

as you can see i am trying to make two custom post types in wordpress,one is called popular_site_seeing and another is called,popular_treking_climbing.the custom post popular_site_seeing is being registered and i can access it from wp admin panel but,another post type popular_treking_climbing is not shown on wp admin panel.what am i doing wrong here? everywhere i searched,it says the way i am doing is the correct way.

Comment: You could start by returning the value register_post_type. If there is an error, you'll be able to see it: `$result = register_post_type( 'popular_site_seeing', $args); var_dump($result);`  I would do that both times and see what the error is.

Answer (score 1):

**WordPress custom post type name length longer than 20 characters**

WordPress is standard using a max of 20 characters for the custom post type name. You can add the code for a new custom post type in your functions.php but if the name is longer than 20 characters WordPress doesn’t accept it.

I’ve searched for it and found the solution to get a custom post type with a name longer than 20 characters:

1. **Open in /wp-includes the post.php file and search for the following line:**

   if ( strlen( $post_type ) > 20 )
   return new WP_Error( ‘post_type_too_long’, __( ‘Post types cannot exceed 20 characters in length’ ) );
2. **Change this line to: (I took 50 characters in my example)**

   if ( strlen( $post_type ) > 50 )
   return new WP_Error( ‘post_type_too_long’, __( ‘Post types cannot exceed 50 characters in length’ ) );
3. **Then open your database and edit the wp_posts > post_type column from 20 characters to 50 characters.**

Remember that if you update WordPress you need to do these steps every time.

better way is you must give short name of your post type (less then 20 character).